# dockerfile with apt-get update failing

Tags: docker, apt, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to build a docker images with the below content as starting 2 lines.

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04 
RUN apt-get update --fix-missing && apt-get -y install nginx sed python-setuptools python-dev build-essential  uwsgi-plugin-python supervisor vim
```

I am getting `E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/openssl_1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.4_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: x.x.x.x 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?`

But when I tried to run something before `apt-get update` line , its working fine. It looks like some kind of delay ( even a echo command ) is making it successful.Can someone please help me to understand if it is correct.

Thanks in advance.